# How can a query select dates from only a specific academic year?

Tags: sql, oracle

This may be simple, but I cannot figure out the correct and simplest way to query a table which contains a date col to return the rows in which the date belongs to the current academic year.

Knowing that for academic year I mean the period from the 1st of September of a year to the 31st of august of the next one, how can you obtain the right dataset
from a table that look like this:

```
TABLE
----
Date
----
12/08/2015
15/06/2015
01/09/2015 <-
07/10/2015 <-
09/11/2015 <-
21/12/2015 <-
15/01/2016 <-
18/03/2016 <-
28/04/2016 <-
29/06/2016 <-
30/07/2016 <-
12/09/2016
23/11/2016
```

Comment: it's of course something to address in the where clause... but what's the logic to put in use ?

Comment: it should be something that work around the sysdate i guess... but i can't pin out the right conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an Oracle equivalent of Andomar's post -

```
select
   *
from
   dts
where
   case
     when extract (month from dt) < 9 then extract (year from dt) - 1
       else extract (year from dt)
         end = extract (year from sysdate)
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75a16/1/0

Comment: nope, don't work, it only consider the rows of the current year, meaning that the rows of sep-oct-nov-dec of the previous year are not being selected

Comment: my mistakes, it works. it's rather confusing tough, can you please explain what's happening under the hood ? supposing extract do exactly that, extracting the piece of info required, what does the end = ... means ?

Comment: The `extract` function extracts just the piece of the date of interest (month, year, etc.) as a number. The case statement as a whole starts with the word `case` and ends with the word `end`. Afterward the `=` is just a normal comparison operator like you'd typically use in the `where` clause. For example, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75a16/3/0 which has the 2 expressions in the select list. The query I gave you essentially compares X and Y -- in 2nd example -- and returns where they are the same.

Comment: starting to get it, i understand that end is year or year -1 depending on the  when else statment but i don't understand how or rather when such value si assigned to it. You have already provided enough info tough, so i'll look it up by myself. thank you very much sir, really appreciated ! Cheers

Comment: just one more question, is there a way to save locally this dataset in my procedure to use it after the query is submitted ?

Comment: If you want to save the result set as a table, write a `CTAS` query (create table as select). Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76268/1/0

Comment: i want to save it in the procedure context, with such scope it should be dropped when the procedure has finished.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `case` to convert a date to its academic year.  For SQL Server, that could look like:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
where   case 
        when month(DateColumn) < 9 then year(DateColumn) - 1
        else year(DateColumn)
        end = year(getdate())
```

Comment: @darkpirate: In that case you'd have to specify your DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)   Date functions very between them.

Comment: ok, maybe i'm missing something. but i'm not sure that year nor month are actual functions in oracle, i mean, all those guides on the to_date to_char function will be silly otherwise

Comment: i swear i posted a comment saying it was an oracle db... damn, i'm sorry

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to add four months (*or* subtract eight months) from both sides of the equation and extract the year:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(mydate, 4)) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 4));
```

or:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(my_date, 4), 'YEAR') = TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, 4), 'YEAR');
```

Adding four months ==> treating `2015-09-01` as `2016-01-01`; subtracting eight months ==> treating `2015-09-01` as `2015-01-01`.

Answer (score 0):

I probably missed something but I'll post anyhow in case it is this simple:

```
select *
from dts
where dt between to_date('2015-09-01','YYYY-MM-DD') 
             and to_date('2016-08-31','YYYY-MM-DD');
```